# UITextView & pagingEnabled: how to 'turn the page' properly

Tags: iphone, uitextview

I would like to have two (or more) iPhone screens full of editable text (like a book). I don't want to scroll through the text, but swipe (again like a book) from one page of editable text to the next.

What I tried to do is:

1) Have an UITextView covering my entire screen

2) Set the pagingEnabled to YES.

However, this will NOT give me the desired effect. As it is stated: if I set pagingEnabled to YES, the scroll view stops on **multiples of the scroll view’s bounds** when the user scrolls.

How do I teach UITextView and pagingEnabled that it should stop the view after **one iPhone screen of text** and then continue one the next screen (if the user swipes to that screen).

I'm not bothered about animation yet (that why the other examples discussed here didn't really help, as all of them discuss animation of page turners), but I'd like to know more about the structure of how to accomplish what I want to accomplish.

I'd be most grateful for any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could achieve the above by implementing Events methods,I think the rest u will get from the below links,

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=634462
Half paging in scrollview.
http://www.inediblesoftware.com/blog/2009/04/05/uiscrollview-paging-hack/

Comment: Sorry, beginner's question, but what events methods are you thinking about?

Comment: hi,I means to get the touch events in the following methods:touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event , you can calculate the dragging distance between two touches and update your view accordingly.